# file read() const correctness

Tags: c++, constants

Assume I am writing a class to wrap windows' file HANDLE to give functionality to read/write from files easily. The class has a functions called `read(buffer& out)` that reads data from the file.

The question is, does `read()` need to be `const` or not?

On one hand, it should be `const` because it doesn't change the file.
On the other hand, it shouldn't be `const` because it changes the HANDLE (the HANDLE to the file which shows where to read).

What do you think?

Comment: Herb Sutter gave a talk a couple of years ago where he said that for C++11, "`const` means thread-safe". So the question is, call you safely call `read()` from two threads simultaneously without any (client-side) locking? I suspect the answer is no, so then the function should not be `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not const. Modifies the file handle position.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your class - I'll call it `FileAccessor` - is effectively orchestrating operations on the file.  Say you want to have a function implementing some algorithm processing the file, and it wants to display some diagnostic information by calling `output_diagnostics(const FileAccessor& h)`, what information could it reasonable display that couldn't interfere with the algorithm calling `output_diagnostics`?  It could perhaps output the current position / bytes-offset in the file.  A function to get that position should be `const`.  There might be other things, such as whether the file's locked in some way, the file size or filesystem path - all seem fair to make `const`.  But, if it does a `read` from the file it's modifying what the algorithm calling `output_diagnostic` can expect should it later do a `read`, a "truncate from the current position" and all manner of other operations, and for that reason the `read` function should *not* be `const`.