# Implementing const methods of an interface and file reading

Tags: c++, constants, mutable, const-correctness

I have an interface that has bunch of const methods. In one of the implementation of the interface I need to read the requested information from a file. As pointed out for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324018/file-read-const-correctness) it is in fact NOT a const operation because the file handle changes with reading.

There are basically three options to go about this I am aware of:

1) Use temporary file handle on every request.

2) Use PIMPL.

3) Use `mutable` on the file handle.

The first option is obviously an overkill and with lots of requests adds lots of overhead. The second option adds indirection but seems to be pretty standard solution. The third option however has no overhead and no indirection but it is basically a blank cheque for changes. Then again though the PIMPL idiom does the same thing in just more convoluted but arguably more controlled manner.

What would be the proper/preferred way of doing file reading in a const method without prejudice to const-correctness?

Comment: (3) Yes if the file handle is NOT part of the observable state of the object.

Comment: @RichardCritten That is the tricky part isn't it. The file handle is not part of the interface nor it can be referenced directly but once mutable it also allows for example writing to the file in const methods and that would (via const methods of the interface) be observable from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put the file handle object in your class, directly.

Have your class contain a `std::shared_ptr` (as opposed to a regular pointer in order to avoid dealing with `RAII` yourself), which even a const method can use, to read from.

(You may/may not have to do something in your class's copy constructor and/or assignment operator, in order to get the right semantics for these situations, with respect to the file handle)

Comment: I inherit from QObject so no copying to worry about and therefore std::unique_ptr could be used imho. The suggestion is pretty good though as it clearly preserves the const-correctness without the PIMPL's indirection. Just curious but would mutable file handle object be worse/problematic if an object would be a sole user of that handle?

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't object to using a mutable object. This merely a way to avoid doing that.